# Where do bailiffs store seized goods prior to auction?

Tags: england-and-wales, civil-law

Is the answer to this legally regulated? I would expect yes quite closely so, but do not Know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current regime for "taking control of goods" is set out in Part 3 of the [Tribunals, Courts and Enforcement Act 2007](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2007/15/contents) and enforcement agents (bailiffs) follow the procedure set out in its [Schedule 12](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2007/15/schedule/12). Further detail on process is given in the [Taking Control of Goods Regulations 2013](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2013/1894).

The procedure allows goods to be taken away, among other possibilities. In the 2013 regulations, the relevant rules for storage include:

- It must be at "a place which is within a reasonable distance from the place where control was taken of the goods" except in exceptional circumstances (Regulation 19).
- "The storage must be secure and the conditions of that storage such as to prevent damage to or deterioration of the goods for so long as they remain in the enforcement agent's control." (Regulation 34(1)(c))

The purpose of the first requirement is probably to make it easier for the owner to recover the goods, if they pay their debt before the goods are sold. Agents have to tell debtors the procedure for collection, and there can also be a fee charged for the storage. The security requirement is in everyone's interest because it makes it more likely the value of the goods will be preserved.

Many agents are private-sector actors, and some are court employees. In any case, it's up to them to find some appropriate storage facility. There isn't a single official place which is the designated one for all agents in the locality.